# How can I comment these explanation?

Tags: linear-algebra

There are column vectors and there exists comments about it. it's given in the image. i don't understand inconsistent, consistent because the translation of these terms into my language is unmeaningfull.

could you comment on the image. really thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The notation **consistent** and **inconsistent** refers to the number of solutions of an equation system:

- If the system has AT LEAST one solution, we say it's consistent.
- If the system has NO possible solutions, we say it's inconsistent.

I hope you will be able to understand the 4 statements of your problem given this information. If not comment and i'll edit.

Comment: thanks for your explanation. i can't construct relation between v1,v2,v3,v4..how can I comment whether if v1,v2...then bla bla. it's actually my problem..really sorry

Comment: @kidonat So what relation between v1,v2,v3,v4 do you want to comment? Maybe I can help with that. Do you understand the statements a,b,c and d?